# Appending messages to chatbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

So I am currently busy with a chatbox, which stores all the messages in Firebase and immediately appends the message into the messagebox. The problem is that Firebase obtains messages in a certain order, I append to the chatbox in a certain way, and when I refresh it, it is different again.

```
function init_chatbox() {
    $('.empty-chat').show();
    ref.child("/chatboxes/{{ chatbox.pk }}/messages/").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
        $('.empty-chat').hide();

        var object = snapshot.val();
        var key = snapshot.key();
        var name = "";

        ref.child("/users/" + object['user_id'] + "/name").once('value', function(snapshot) {
            name = snapshot.val();

            var timestamp = object['timestamp'];
            var message = object['message'];

            extra_html = ' <a href="#/" class="remove" onclick="delete_message(\'' + key + '\')">(remove)</a><a href="#/" class="edit" onclick="load_modal(\'' + key + '\')">(edit)</a>';



            $('ul.chat-messages').append('<li class="' + key +'"><p class="author"><span>' + name + '</span><span></span><span class="time" data-livestamp="' + timestamp + '"></span>' + extra_html + '</p><p class="message">' + message + '</p></li>');
        });
    });
```

When I have the code like this (with `.append`), it shows the code like this immediately:

```
Kevin 2 hours ago (remove)(edit)
some message here
John 10 minutes ago (remove)(edit)
test
John 2 minutes ago (remove)(edit)
msg
Kevin few seconds ago (remove)(edit)
test
```

And when i refresh the page, the message will be at the top, like the order should be.
Here is the thing, I also tried to `.prepend`, but it just gives another other, which isn't right either (posts the new message on top, but when refreshing it displays the good order, but then the lastest message on top).

I hope someone can help me with this, have been trying to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [orderByChild()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html) in the firebase docs.

Basically you can order the messages by their **timestamp**. Like this:

```
ref.child("/chatboxes/{{ chatbox.pk }}/messages/")
   .orderByChild("timestamp")
   .on("child_added", function (snap) { ... });
```

Messages with the lowest timestamp will come first.

Comment: I have indeed tried `orderByChild()`, in combination with `.append()`, although it seems to stay the same (displays right order after refresh, appends new message to bottom directly). Tried it with `.prepend()`, posts new message to top, but timestamp in wrong order ..